# Plural of “Animus/Anima”

Tags: grammatical-number, latin, grammatical-gender

What is the plural of the words “animus” and “anima”? In any context (literary, Jung psychology, apothecary etc.). Is there English v. Latin differences? Interwebs are no help: versions differ from “animuses”, to “animi”, to uncountable. “Animuses” is correct as native English plural, if I understand correctly (then “animas” for feminine?). If we take Latin route, would it be “animi” for masculine, and “animae” for feminine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the OED, the Jungian terms *anima* and *animus* have no plural form in English.

> ### *animus* /ˈænɪməs/.
>
> **No pl.**
>
> Etymology: a. L. *animus* (1) soul, (2) mind, (3) mental impulse, disposition, passion.
>
> 1. Actuating feeling, disposition in a particular direction, animating spirit or temper, usually of a hostile character; *hence*, animosity.
> 2. *Psychol.* Jung’s term for the masculine component of a female personality. Cf. **anima**.
>
> ---
>
> ### *anima* /ˈænɪmə/.
>
> *Psychol*.
>
> Etymology: L., ‘mind, soul’.
>
> Jung’s term for the inner part of the personality or character, as opposed to the persona or outer part; also, the feminine component of a male personality. Cf. **animus** <sup>2</sup>.

They are in essence mass nouns, not count nouns.

In English, that is.

In Latin, where they do not mean what they do per Jung, *anima* and *animus* are unremarkable nominative singulars of the first and second declensions, respectively. They therefore form their nominative plural and genitive singular as *anima > animae* and *animus > animi*, and genitive plurals as *anima > animarum* and *animus > animorum*.   So soul, souls/soul’s,  and souls’.

- *Nullum autem est, nisi quod animus ex se sibi invenit.*   ― Seneca the Younger 
   [~ “There can be no good except for what the soul discovers for itself within itself.”]
- *Magnificat anima mea dominum.*   ― J.S. Bach ☺  
   [traditionally translated as “My soul doth magnify the Lord.”]

Comment: Wish I could +2 you for quoting both Seneca and Bach.

Comment: What about archaic pharmacological meaning of “anima”? [MW reads](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anima): **2** _in old pharmacy_ **a:** the active ingredient of an animal or vegetable drug **b:** a dried plant juice or an aqueous extract

Comment: @theUG I don’t know.  All the casually scrawled recipes my apothecary receives from my physicker are always in Latin anyway. :)

Comment: Actually Bach wrote the music; the lyricist was either Mary or St Jerome.

Comment: What would be gender-neutral version of “souls” in Latin? Sort of “them souls”. Do mixed group of souls would just use masculine version (e.g. as in Spanish)? Likewise, would singular soul of unknown gender be masculine, or take plural form like English gender-neutral “they” instead of convoluted “he or she”?

Comment: @theUg Latin didn’t have masculine souls and feminine souls. But yes, mixed groups take masculine in Latin. Also, *they* is not necessarily “plural” in sense in English, only in agreement.  If someone can’t find their own way home, there is still only one of them. We just don’t know anything about them is all.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster gives plurals when they form irregularly, as in *louse*, *child*, or *sheep*. M-W doesn't comment at all when a noun has no plural, like *mathematics* or *information*.  In the case of animus/anima, M-W doesn't list a plural, which to my mind indicates the M-W considers it either (a) without plural; or (b) with a plural formed along standard lines.

In English, often a Latin ending is used for one meaning, and the anglicized ending is used in another related, but different way. *Index* is a good example. In technical writing, *index* can be either a measurement or a table of references at the back of a book. The former is pluralized *indices* and the latter is pluralized *indexes* (anglicized). This precise usage is common, but not entirely standardized, I should think.

All this is to say that if you find yourself in a situation that requires a plural for animus or anima, you might use something of the same approach: -es/-s for general, and -i/-ae for technical (like Jung's use), or vice versa.

Comment: OED. Good call. Without the OED mine makes sense, but as usual, I yield to the scholarly gentlemen from the Mother Country.